# Joining feature collections, keep non-matching features in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-join, feature-collection

I have a sample of tile centroids:

```
var BGD = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Bangladesh"));

var projection='EPSG:4326'; // WGS84 lat lon
var dx=0.1;
var dy=0.1;

var proj=ee.Projection(projection).scale(dx, dy);
var grid=BGD.geometry().coveringGrid(proj);

var getCentroids = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({centralPoint: feature.centroid(0.1)});
};

var tileCenter = grid.map(getCentroids);

var tileCentroids = tileCenter.map(function(f) {
  var centroid = ee.Feature(ee.List(f.get('centralPoint')));
  return centroid;
});
```

I want to identify whether each tile centroid intersects a protected area and, if yes, collect information on the area.

```
var parks = ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons")
///.filterBounds(area);

var properties = ["NAME"];
```

I tried this join function, but the resulting feature collection drops any grid centroids that don't overlap a protected area.

```
var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo'
});


var joinAll = ee.Join.saveAll('matched').apply(tileCentroids, parks, spatialFilter);

var tileCentroids2 = joinAll.map(function(feature){
  var joinedFeat =  ee.List(feature.get('matched'));
  var polygon = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(joinedFeat).first());
  return ee.Feature(feature.copyProperties(polygon, properties)).select(properties);
});
```

Can I modify the function so that all original grids are retained, even if there is no join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by using **outer** parameter in 'saveAll' method with the option **true** selected. It is also necessary to include an If in the return for managing **not matched** features. Modifications look as follow.

```
var joinAll = ee.Join.saveAll({matchesKey: 'matched',
                               outer: true
                              }).apply(tileCentroids, parks, spatialFilter);

var tileCentroids2 = joinAll.map(function(feature){
  var joinedFeat =  ee.List(feature.get('matched'));
  var polygon = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(joinedFeat).first());
  return ee.Algorithms.If(joinedFeat, 
                          ee.Feature(feature.copyProperties(polygon, properties)).select(properties), 
                          ee.Feature(feature));
});
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/439babf80b88a984292ab72ab2479ba8) in GEE code editor, I got following result. It can be observed all features belonging to **tileCentroids** displayed in **tileCentroids2** layer. However, the information displayed at Inspector Tab corresponds to an aleatory feature that matches the Spatial Filter.

[image]

When the click is on a feature that doesn't match the Spatial Filter the information displayed at Inspector Tab looks as follows:

[image]

So, you can keep non-matching features in Earth Engine managed in this way.